# Draft angle and undercut analyses

Tags: mesh

Is Blender capable of producing draft angle analysis and undercut analysis with STL files? I see that it can produce a heat map for wall thickness, find overhang faces, etc., but I can't seem to find anything for draft angle and undercut.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No, I  don't think Blender has anything specifically for that purpose as far as I know, but being a generalist 3d application maybe some of the existing tools can help in what you want. What exactly are you looking for?  Have you looked into the 3d printing mesh analysis tools? Maybe those can help. Other than that maybe some normals based Cycles procedural shader can display the information you want.

Comment: I'm hoping to assess a collection parts to see if they satisfy the draft and undercut requirements. The parts are to be injection moulded rather than 3D printing, which is why draft angles and undercuts could cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

In the 3D printing game it would be called the 'self-support angle'.

This setup assumes that the upside of your STL/mesh is oriented in the +Z direction.

[image: 3D printing self-support angle analysis in Blender]

The example is targeted at a 3D printer which behaves as follows:

- prints perfectly up to 30 degree angle (white colour)
- in most cases manages to print in angles between 30 and 45 degrees (yellow colour)
- anything over 45 degrees will collapse

The ColorRamp can hold values from 0 to 1 while the Normal is 0 to 90 degrees.

- Value 0 = 0 degrees
- Value 1 = 90 degrees

As a result for this example:

- Value 0.333 = 30 degrees
- Value 0.5 = 45 degrees

---

See a nice comparison of how the self-support angle affects the 3D print (note that it is measured from horizontal surface rather than vertical direction in this photograph :/).
[image: self-support angle (from horizontal plane rather than vertical diretion)]

Answer (score 1):

That is more of a CAD type of workflow. CAD creates models using constraints, While blender is exclusively for aesthetic modeling.

Although, you may be looking for the "Bevel" modifier, which should be able to produce the desired effect.

DOCS:

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html

EDIT: I should also point out that since blender is purely for aesthetic purposes, you really dont need precision in your models to the extent that i sense you are looking for. If you truly believe that you must have a level of precision that you find difficult to achieve in blender, it is most likely that you should be using something like FreeCAD or one of AutoDesk's products

Comment: I'm just hoping to analyse a collection injection moulded parts for draft angles and undercuts. I'm only running analyses on existing models created elsewhere, so I won't be adding/changing the draft angles. Even if the input models are precisely made, does Blender somehow lose precision in the process? For instance, could Blender's mesh be too coarse?

Comment: no, no precision is lost,or even spared in the standard use of the software. However, since things dont need to be absolutly perfect for visual purposes you can aproximate in many areas. precision requires the time to be precise. that was all i meant when i said "difficult"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously in my comment I am not entirely sure what Draft and Undercut mean in term of geometric properties, or what you wish to analyze about them. Could you provide some more insight or more details about what you want to achieve?

Is it some sort of color map with tolerances or angles? Perhaps hilight parts of the geometry that don't fall into some threshold?

For most people here this is probably an unknown area. Maybe show some pictures or post an example of what you wish to achieve.

From a quick google search I got the rough impression they are related to angles parts for injection molding must have so they can be easily removed from their molds.

As stated by Konner Rasmussen these things are probably ore suited for CAD applications with NURBS or solid modeling based geometry. Blender's meshes are probably more than precise enough for most requirements, however it's polygon based mesh geometry may be less adequate for such type of analysis.

That being said, *Mesh Analysis* tools doesn't seem to cover what you are looking for, so I am wondering if somehow a cycles procedural shader could do what you are looking for.

Combining the *Normal Output* of a *Geometry* Node in cycles your could through trigonometry calculate angles using a *Math* node.

Would this serve your purpose?

[image: Cycles Geometry Node]

Comment: Indeed, drafts and undercuts are only pertinent to injection moulding. Drafts are needed to eject the part. Typically, draft analysis highlights the faces that don't have the satisfactory draft angle, like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rGXuWkvGTW8/maxresdefault.jpg). I wonder if Mesh Analysis is good enough for measuring draft angles / undercuts?

Comment: That looks like the kind of thing a procedural shader with a some trigonometry as illustrated in the image above could achieve. Mesh analysis doesn't seem to have the tools you need.

Comment: not sure about undercut either, but draft angle: https://www.google.com/search?q=draft+angle&oq=draft+angle&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j0l4.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8